# Destructor called when returning value

Tags: c++

I've got a class and I'm trying to return it's instance, but the destructor is called before I can return it, which and when it really does fall out of scope in a later functions it's destructor is called again and causes a break. I edited it to fix the error, but I was wondering if it's supposed to be calling it's destructor.

```
CBuffer BufferReader::read(const int size){
    const auto raw = read_raw(); 
    skip(size);
    return CBuffer(raw, size, true);

    // Dstructor is called in this example

    CBuffer out(read_raw(), size, true);
    skip(size);
    return std::move(out);
}
```

Comment: Returning theoretically makes a copy to return, so the original is theoretically destroyed. Given a properly-defined class, that's not an issue.

Comment: unless [RVO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) comes in, it should call destructor after been copied/moved.

Comment: Why don't you show the basics of the CBuffer class?  Not every function, but the constructor used here, the copy constructor, destructor, and key data members?  You might get helpful advice about how to improve the copy constructor to make this work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are returning a copy of the CBuffer.  The original CBuffer that was created inside the function is destroyed when the function exits -- at least logically.  Typically a compiler will elide the copy as an optimization unless that optimization is disabled (by making a debug build, for example).

Using `std::move` doesn't really change this.  The copy that is created can just be done more efficiently by stealing the guts out of the original `CBuffer`.  The original `CBuffer` still has to be destroyed, it just may not contain any real data.  A move constructor always needs to leave the original object in a valid state, so it can be safely destroyed.

For example:

```
struct CBuffer {
    char* data;

    CBuffer(CBuffer&& original)
       : data(original.data)
    {
        original.data = nullptr;
    }

    ~CBuffer() { delete [] data; }  // data may be null, but that is fine
                                    // delete will not do anything in that case.
};
```

If you can use `std::vector` instead, that is even better, since it handles these details for you.

Comment: The destructor is still called when I return it with std::move, edit shows the code with std::move, to my understanding that converts out into a r value and no copy should be performed.

Comment: @JoshuaWaring: When a move happens, it is simply an optimized way of copying.  It doesn't change whether or not a destructor is called.

Comment: CBuffer only contains a int size and a void* data, what would happen to that data if the move is called, would it become a nullptr? because the CBuffers destructor tries to delete data.

Comment: I haven't defined a copy constructor or a move constructor, but it seems to be the perfect solution. The more you know.

Answer (score 0):

`std::move` doesn't *do* anything to the object, all it does is forward its argument right through by reference and make it bind like an rvalue. Put another way, it simply returns an anonymous rvalue reference to the object, think:

```
template<class T>
T&& std::move(T&& arg)
{
    return static_cast<T&&>(arg);
}
```

(It's a little more complex than that, but I'm aiming for legibility)

What's actually happening here at the exit is:

```
CBuffer rv(std::move(out));
return rv;
```

Which is calling CBuffer's move constructor.

A lot of people fall into the trap of thinking std::move actually performs the move, IMHO it's poorly named.

If you write the code this way:

```
CBuffer BufferReader::read(const int size)
{
    CBuffer out(read_raw(), size, true);
    skip(size);
    return out;
}
```

Then most compilers should be able to perform 'return value optimization'; that is, they will quietly pretend you did something equivalent to:

```
void BufferReader::read(const int size, CBuffer* out)
{
    new (out) CBuffer(read_raw(), size, true); //in-place new
    skip(size);
}
```

and at the calling site where you have

```
CBuffer x = reader.read(size);
```

they'll pretend you're writing

```
CBuffer* x = (CBuffer*)alloca(sizeof(CBuffer));
reader.read(size, &x);
```

Again, simplifying somewhat, what the code above does is allocate a CBuffer on the stack and then in-place initializes it inside the callee. Which saves performing a copy in the return.